# Did Garak know Julian was to join section 31

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, character-motivation, section-31

in the first season of DS9 garak seems to specifically seek out Julian Bashir and then across the duration of the TV show has regular lunch with him and involves him in assorted Obsidian order Hi-jinks. why did he do this instead of simply bringing what he knew to Sisko? is it possible that a time-traveller informed him that Julian would in the future be the one to get the cure to the Morphogenic virus, helping end the war and save cardassia?

Was there any material in the novels or extra-tv content that indicated that Garak saw this coming?

Comment: You might add a line describing how this could be known, e.g., "Was there any material in the novels or extra-tv content that indicated that Garak saw this coming?"

Comment: I believe in one of the episodes Garak, under some sort of duress, explains to Julian why Garak tried to become best buds. One of the reasons I believe was Julian's naivety and inability to keep a poker face, something that would make Sisko a much less easily manipulatable target.

Comment: I have seen this episode, but then again Garak was also a notorious liar and frankly  by season 3+ Julian was considerably less naive, while there where still plenty of federation and bajoran officers dotted about the station.  Also it seemingly only took him a few weeks at worst to pick bashir out, despite having never met him previously.

Comment: Garak was a member of the Obsidian Order. It's very possible, considering a relatively recent war, that the Obsidian Order had run ins with Section 31. It's also likely that the Order knew about Bashir's modifications and that this would make him a good recruit for Section 31. This is all speculation and there is absolutely no evidence to back it up

Comment: There's also the reverse possibility. Section 31 may have had addiitonal interest in Bashir due to his association with Garak.